# How can I reinstall ubuntu focal 20.04 on encrypted system?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, 20.04, luks, reinstall

I'm a very long time ubuntu user (over a decade) but have not been here as I've had no issues with Ubuntu. With the arrival of 20.04 LTS I decided to encrypt my data (or system if needed). I'm looking for the following:

- Method to reinstall ubuntu with LUKS encryption on a previous LUKS encrypted ubuntu install on a dual boot system with Win10.
- Keep all my personal files (ie `/home` folder) intact, with or without a separate partition. I do not wish to move everything out, reinstall and then move stuff back in.
- Simple GUI based approach through the standard installer. I know how to use the command line but I'd rather not, especially for something as sensitive as encryption.

What I'm looking for is basically the same as this document: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) except that I need it on an LUKS encrypted system/partition. I tried doing this on a spare system with 20.04, and I could not find a way of telling the installer the passphrase to the encrypted system. The end result was a reinstall that wouldn't boot or the encrypted partition gets wiped out. I also tried to run installer with and without pre-unlocking the encrypted partition but to no avail'.

I am able to do all of the above with Fedora,OpenSUSE,Manjaro, (although they only do this when /home is on separate partition, which is fine for me) so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the my personal experiments using the Ubuntu 20.04 installer, online research, and asking various forums (and lack of answers there), I conclude that as of today, there is no way to do all of the following:

- Installing/reinstalling Ubuntu ...
- using the installer GUI ...
- on a pre-encrypted system (LUKS, with separate `/home` partition or not) without destroying pre-existing personal files...
- with dual booting another OS.

Of course there are ways of doing this if you rely on the command line, which I was looking to avoid. I've decided to switch to Fedora 32 as it meets all these requirements. Ubuntu served me rather well for over a decade, hope to return when the above issue is fixed.

For those interested in my Fedora 32 setup:

- Dual-boot setup with Windows 10.
- Reuse (DO NOT FORMAT) `/boot/efi` partition from Windows 10 install
- Create UNENCRYPTED `/boot` partition
- Create/Reuse ENCRYPTED `/` partition
- Create/Reuse ENCRYPTED `/home` partition
- Provide Passphrase to unlock above encrypted partitions.
- Post install, added RPMFusion repository and Gnome Tweaks extension

Thats the summary, its been a week and so far things have been great with Fedora 32. I've not really noticed much difference from Ubuntu for my needs (Email, Browsing, viewing photos/videos, music, skype, spreadsheets, documents).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1904270 describes a way to work around this atrocity:

---

**Ubuntu 20.04: Extra Steps for Re-Using Existing LUKS Encrypted Partition**
(replace nvme0n1p8 with your encrypted LUKS partition)

BEFORE starting the installer (if in Ubuntu or Kubuntu live CD desktop), or at the first step (if using Ubuntu Server text-based live CD installer):

```
# open existing LUKS partition (
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 nvme0n1p8_crypt
```

Then, either do this at the end after the installer has run, or boot into a live CD environment (e.g. Kubuntu) and do:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p8 nvme0n1p8_crypt
mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/MainVG-root /mnt/
mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/boot/
mount --rbind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
mount --rbind /sys/ /mnt/sys/
mount --rbind /run/ /mnt/run/
mount --rbind /proc/ /mnt/proc/
chroot /mnt /bin/bash -l
blkid | grep crypto_LUKS
# Example: /dev/nvme0n1p8: UUID="8cb9831a-692e-4b0e-936f-72529a3ed56d" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="139f23d2-a0ff-4f4f-b41f-8083964ac894"
apt install vim
vim /etc/crypttab
# Add a line for the encrypted partiton, e.g:
# nvme0n1p8_crypt UUID="8cb9831a-692e-4b0e-936f-72529a3ed56d" none luks
#
# MAKE SURE There's a newline at end of /etc/crypttab

# update the initramfs
update-initramfs -u -k all

umount -l /mnt

# Optional, probably not needed
grub-install --recheck /dev/nvme0n1
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

---

I'll note that this set of instructions didn't work for me though.

```
mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/MainVG-root /mnt/
```

gave a non-specific error ("wrong fs type, or whatever, etc, etc."). What did work were the commands from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1595535/223875) on SuperUser.SE.