# Full re-install of 20.04 on encrypted drive

Tags: system-installation, encryption

I have a Dell (XPS 13) laptop that has an existing installation of 20.04.  I need to format the disk and re-install 20.04, so I created a live USB and started up the installation process.  However, when I get to the "Installation Type" screen, it says there is no existing operating system detected.  I've tried searching for answers, and so far my best guess is that it's because the SSD is encrypted?

So, rather than booting straight into the installer, I selected "Try Ubuntu", where I was able to select the encrypted drive in the file explorer and enter the drive password.  Live Ubuntu clearly recognizes the drive and lets me explore it.

Does anyone know why it's not recognizing the pre-existing Ubuntu installation?  I haven't tried actually going through with the installation.  I don't need to do anything fancy: I don't have multiple partitions to dual-boot or anything, and I don't care about the data on the encrypted drive.  I just want to wipe it completely and do a clean install of 20.04.

Thanks!

Edit:
So, the post that was [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239311/how-can-i-reinstall-ubuntu-focal-20-04-on-encrypted-system) was one that I had looked at prior to posting; however, some of the circumstances are different. The OP had a dual-boot system with Win 10 and wanted to preserve the files in /home, and possibly even preserve the existing LUKS encryption.  My needs are, I think, simpler because I don't need to dual-boot, have multiple partitions, or preserve any files or pre-existing encryption.

Comment: Until the encrypted partition is mounted, there's no mechanism for the installer to *detect* the existing installation because it's encrypted.  That's why the installer can't 'see' that installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reinstall ubuntu focal 20.04 on encrypted system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239311/how-can-i-reinstall-ubuntu-focal-20-04-on-encrypted-system)

Comment: You haven't said what type of encryption is involved; I've QA-tested (& use on my own systems) older forms of encryption which are no longer used by default thus require a package to be installed (on current *live* installation media) prior to starting the installer; however you've not provided any clues as to what form of encryption you were using.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  The SSD is encrypted using LUKS.